# Grep string in the source code of a given http link

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line

I want to use bash commands line to find a string in the source code of a given web page. Manually I would do it like in those steps:

1. Open https://stackoverflow.com
2. cltrl+U (to get the source code in google chrome)
3. cltrl+F to find the string

Is there a way to do that using bash commands or any other way with python for example?

Comment: Beautiful soup is a python module that might have what you need

Comment: Just be aware that grep on html may not give you the consistent result you hope for, depending on your string and it's specific source. Know your data, if possible.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Would you suggests me any modules you know?

Comment: @PaulHodges Oh okay.. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Beautiful soup ... ?

Comment: I don't work with markup pages often, and when i do I can usually find trustworthy and consistent snippets to grab. Just be careful with your patterns. For example, `<img src="` is a ***horrible*** pattern to search for - the `img` could have any amount of whitespace before it OR after, including newlines. Some very OCD coder might put every relevant string on a line by itself with varying indentation. Typical? No. Smart? Depends, though usually just adds traffic bytes. Possible? Oh, hell yeah, and you can bet the bottom line someone somewhere is doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you are asking for?

```
curl -s https://stackoverflow.com | grep "string"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to `curl` and `grep` then simply:

```
bash$ curl http://some-website.com | grep -F some-string
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use curl or wget CLI tools to get the page and then just grep the result (or pipe to grep).

```
$ curl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698492/grep-string-in-the-source-code-of-a-given-http-link | grep "string in the source code"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0        <title>python - Grep string in the source code of a given http link - Stack Overflow</title>
        <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="name" content="Grep string in the source code of a given http link" />
        <meta name="twitter:description" property="og:description" itemprop="description" content="I want to use bash commands line to find a string in the source code of a given web page. Manually I would do it like in those steps:
            <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed for question &#39;Grep string in the source code of a given http link&#39;" href="/feeds/question/54698492">
                    <h1 itemprop="name" class="grid--cell fs-headline1 fl1 ow-break-word"><a href="/questions/54698492/grep-string-in-the-source-code-of-a-given-http-link" class="question-hyperlink">Grep string in the source code of a given http link</a></h1>
<p>I want to use bash commands line to find a string in the source code of a given web page. Manually I would do it like in those steps:</p>
100  102k  100  102k    0     0   160k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  159k
```

If you want JUST the string, use grep -o:

```
$ curl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698492/grep-string-in-the-source-code-of-a-given-http-link 2>/dev/null | grep -o "string in the source code"
string in the source code
string in the source code
string in the source code
string in the source code
string in the source code
string in the source code
string in the source code
string in the source code
string in the source code
string in the source code
string in the source code
string in the source code
string in the source code
```

Answer (score 2):

once I was in a situation to parse some value from nagios web dashboard,

- have used `wget`
- saved the content in a file ( -O filename )
- used `grep` for getting desired value from the file

  `wget --user='username' --password='password' https://nagios/dashboard -O filename`